# SOQL query :Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, soql

Suppose we have three objects

```
account(id,name)
opportunity(id,amount,stage)
properties(id,address)
```

account object has one to many relationship to opportunity object 
and opportunity object has one to many relationship to  properties object .

And we want SOQL query to display only  name ,stage and address

id,name,amount,stage,address are fields in the objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the "dot" notation you can do joins between tables. Something like this will work:

```
SELECT Address__c,
    Opportunity__r.StageName,
    Opportunity__r.Account.Name
FROM Property__c
```

It's quite basic stuff so looks like you have some reading to do. Check http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm for a start.

And please tag questions with relevant stuff, this has nothing to do with Service Cloud or Chatter.